# Resolving the path of 'web-app/file/misc' from 'src' in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I created a class under 'src' dir. I'm using this code to access the 'images' directory for all files inside 'grails-app':

```
ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.getResource("file/misc").file;
```

I'm having this error when I access it in a 'src' class:

```
application has private access in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
```

Any comment on why is this happening? How can I access "file/misc" when app is deployed to tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved it already:

```
ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getParentContext().getResource("file/recsys").getFile();
```

I'm getting used to Groovy syntax, starting to forget regular Java methods. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From GSP pages, you can do

> ${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'example.gif')}