# Web-App path from outside the Grails Project

Tags: grails, deployment, jar

My Grails Project has a jar, in which i have a method, that uses a file, which is stored in the Grails Web-App directory. Locally I can just type "web-app/myFile" and it gets the file and everything runs smoothly.

But in production when deployed, I get an error, because the file cannot be found. Inside the jar, its a Java Project, so I cannot use any of the Grails render tags or something else.

How can I get to the web-app path from this jar java code when my project is deployed?

Thank you

Comment: Can you inject `def grailsApplication` in the object where you need to read the file? If it is, you can try reading the file with `grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("myFile").getFile();`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587129/resolving-the-path-of-web-app-file-misc-from-src-in-grails

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good practice, though. You may want to create a configuration key for that.